# consistency of verb forms in the structure "as...so..."

Tags: grammar

> As the realm of the mega-wealthy **grows** ever larger, so too **are**
> accompanying issues.

(Sentence modified from https://www.ft.com/content/26806bc4-ff1b-4c7c-b4b0-168486c64ab8)

My intuition tells me the original sentence reads the best, but my grammar radar asks why not make the verbs consistent as follows?

> As the realm of the mega-wealthy **is** growing ever larger, so too **are**
> accompanying issues.

> As the realm of the mega-wealthy **grows** ever larger, so too **do**
> accompanying issues.

Comment: I think the original is an example of careless writing (the accompanying issues are what?) and either of the alternatives would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar radar is very good! **The original sentence is ungrammatical**. As @Kate_Bunting points out, it is not clear what the accompanying issues *are*: read literally, it seems like it's eliding "so too accompanying issues are *grows ever larger*," which is clearly not right.

In fact, the original sentence is not particularly well-constructed in general, since it is also unclear (grammatically) *what* the issues are accompanying--the realm itself or its growth.

As to how to fix it grammatically, I prefer your second suggestion. In your first suggestion

> As the realm of the mega-wealthy is growing ever larger, so too are accompanying issues.

we have the unusual construction *as... is growing*; since we are talking about a current trend, I would expect to see the simple present, rather than the present continuous. Your second suggestion

> As the realm of the mega-wealthy grows ever larger, so too do accompanying issues.

is grammatically correct, but highlights the second problem in the quote: what do the issues accompany?

Comment: Great analysis! Just that "hilight" should be spelled "highlight"?

Comment: The complete original sentence is: As the realm of the mega-wealthy grows ever larger, so too are accompanying issues **such as wealth shame and inheritance guilt**. I thought it might just as well have been:  As the realm of the mega-wealthy grows ever larger, so too are accompanying issues. **For example, more and more of these super-rich are now grappling with wealth shame and inheritance guilt.** Therefore, I only kept a part of it. I think the first part can form a stand-alone sentence, and explanations can come afterwards.